# How can I design a predicate that returns a list of integers of length N such that none of the integers are divisible by the numbers in the list?

Tags: prolog

So I have this predicate divisible that is true if I give a number that can be divided by any of the numbers in the list.

```
divisible([], N) :- fail.
divisible([H|T], X) :- X mod H =:= 0, !.
divisible([H|T], X) :- divisible(T, X).
```

My goal is to design a predicate called *generateList* that returns a list of positive integers of length N such that none of the integers is divisible by any of the numbers in the List D and at the same time is smaller or equal to its rank. I also don't want to include 0 in that list.

This is an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
? - generateList([3,5],5,L). 
[ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1] ;
[ 1, 2, 1, 1, 1] ;
[ 1, 1, 2, 1, 1] ;
[ 1, 1, 1, 2, 1] ; 
[ 1, 1, 1, 1, 2] ; 
[ 1, 2, 2, 1, 1] ;
...(more solutions)
```

I'm trying to use the previous predicate to evaluate the numbers and print the ones that aren't divisible by the numbers in the list D and cannot be smaller than its rank.

I have the base case going which is fairly simple, however I can't seem to come up with the right combination to print the integers correctly or evaluate it.

The predicate divisible does work, but I'm also not sure if I need to change it to make it work with the new predicate.

Comment: My divisible predicate works, I'm just having issues with the generateList predicate. I'm not sure how to approach it

Comment: I updated the post to try and reflect my problem a bit better. The generateList predicate should return a list of positive integers of length N such that none of the integers are divisible by any of the numbers in the List D and at the same time is smaller than its rank.

Comment: I wish I could give you more info, but that's all the information I have as well. I have no more info to use to figure out this problem

Comment: Yeah, this is an assignment from my instructor